# Silverlight 5 / Sharepoint Client OM - VB to read from SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, silverlight

I'm using VB.Net 4.0/Silverlight 5 and the SharePoint Client Object Model. I have SharePoint Foundation 2010 running on localhost.

I've been trying for days to read some values from a list, with no success.

I have a List called 'pfa'. The list has 3 columns; FullName, JobTitle and PhoneNumber.

I just need some sample code to read the items from the list and display them in a textbox.

Can anyone help? My latest code is below. And, this is just attempting to read the Id: field for now.

Thanks,

JT

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports System.Windows.Documents
Imports System.Windows.Input
Imports System.Windows.Media
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation
Imports System.Windows.Shapes
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Client
Imports SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client


Namespace Jason
    Partial Public Class MainPage
        Inherits UserControl
        Private oWebsite As Web
        Private collList As ListCollection
        Private collListItem As ListItemCollection
        Private listInfo As IEnumerable(Of List)

        Public Sub New()
            InitializeComponent()
        End Sub

        Private Sub onQuerySucceeded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs)
            MessageBox.Show("Request Succeeded")
            Dim updateUI As UpdateUIMethod = AddressOf DisplayInfo
            Me.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(updateUI)
        End Sub

        Private Sub onQueryFailed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As ClientRequestFailedEventArgs)
            MessageBox.Show("Request failed. " & args.Message & vbLf & args.StackTrace)
        End Sub

        Private Sub DisplayInfo()
            Dim oListItem As SP.ListItem
            For Each oListItem In collListItem
                MyOutput.Text += vbLf & "Id: " & oListItem.Id
            Next oListItem
        End Sub

        Private Delegate Sub UpdateUIMethod()

        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim clientContext As ClientContext = clientContext.Current
            Dim oList As SP.List = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("pfa")
            oWebsite = clientContext.Web
            Dim _Query = SP.CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery
            Dim collListItem As ListItemCollection = oList.GetItems(_Query)

            clientContext.Load(collListItem)

            clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(AddressOf onQuerySucceeded, AddressOf onQueryFailed)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: I've tried everything. Have just added my latest code in the original message. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the fact that you have two separate variables named `collListItem`. The global one is never used. The `collListItem` in the scope of the button click event handler is created and loaded, but the variable goes out of scope outside of the click handler, and is reclaimed by the garbage collector.

First, change this:

```
Dim collListItem As ListItemCollection = oList.GetItems(_Query)
```

To this:

```
collListItem = oList.GetItems(_Query)
```

Now you're loading the data into the global variable rather than the local variable.

Comment: rjcup - thank you so much. I've been struggling with this for days. I think I've gone code blind by staring at it for so long. I tried your change, and it works. I could kick myself! Thanks again.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes. HTH.

Comment: Just be mindful to clean up your disposable objects that you're declaring globally (IE: Private oWebsite As Web). If SharePoint reclaims it, it writes to the ULS logs and then you'll have an admin to deal with.

Comment: Is there a tutorial I can read anywhere on cleaning up disposable objects? I've not been doing this so far!

Comment: Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248.aspx This is the disposable objects best practices.

Comment: Np dude. I'd recommend picking up one of the Wrox books or "Inside WSS 3.0" if you're going to be working with SharePoint for more than the short term.

Comment: I think I need a book on Visual Studio 2010, VB.net, Silverlight 5, and WSS! All of these are new to me. And I should probably really be doing my stuff in C# as that's what most code samples seem to be in. Thanks.

Comment: Is WSS 3.0 still current in SharePoint 2010 onwards?

Comment: BTW, My company's SharePoint is SharePoint Online, and I use Foundation as my dev box.

Comment: The core infrastructure of WSS 3.0 is still in place in SharePoint 2010. SharePoint Online (O365) requires a different mechanism for authentication. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx